# Fundamental group of the Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Proof that fundamental group of the Klein bottle have the next two different presentations:
a) $Gen(a,b \,; baba^{-1}=1)$,
b) $Gen(a,b \,; a^{2}b^{2}=1)$.

I have the proof of (a) and I can prove that (a) is isomorphic to (b) but I need show that (b) is the fundamental group of the Klein bottle using Seifert.

Thanks.

Comment: The Klein bottle can be thought of as the non-orientable surface of genus 2, hence has the surface word $aabb$. (Prove that the surface given by the word $aabb$ is homeomorphic to the surface given by $abab^{-1}$ by cutting along the diagonal and pasting). Then the Klein bottle is obtained from $S^1\vee S^1$ by attaching a 2-cell along the path given by the word $aabb$. Apply Van Kampen for attaching 2-cells.

Comment: Alternatively, choose an open cover of the Klein bottle by two Möbius strips $M_1, M_2$ (think about why this is possible). Each of those deformation retract onto a circle, hence have fundamental group $\Bbb{Z}$. The intersection $M_1\cap M_2$ also deformation retracts onto a circle. The generating loop of $M_1\cap M_2$ is mapped to twice the generating loop of $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively, under the induced inclusions (try to see this by drawing pictures). Now apply Van Kampen.